# Knockout ObservableArray - How to apply Kendo widget to new instances

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo and am having issues applying a widget to a dynamic KO array.  I have an observable array that loads an initial set of elements and allows a kendoNumericTextBox to be applied to each box via a style.  However after adding an element to the array, the Kendo widget no longer appears. I have created a fiddle that displays the behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlesticks66/WekFG/

View

```
<code>
    <div data-bind="foreach:rows">
        <input class="percentage" data-bind="value:percent" />
    </div>    
    <button data-bind="click:addRow">add row</button>

</code>
```

VM

```
<code>
    function newVM(){
        self=this;
        self.rows = ko.observableArray([
            { percent: 0 },
            { percent: 0.25 },
            { percent: 0.50 }    ]);

        self.addRow = function(){ 
            this.rows.push({percent:0});
        };
        return self;
    }
</code>
```

JS to apply Kendo

```
<code>
    $(".percentage").kendoNumericTextBox({
                format: "p0",
                min: 0,
                max: 1,
                step: 0.25
            }).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
</code>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because

```
$(".percentage").kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "p0",
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            step: 0.25
        }).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

runs only for the inputs that exist in the page when it is applied.

I suggest moving it to a custom binding(kendo-ui might already have a custom binding for that), like this (updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WekFG/3/):

html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:rows">
    <input class="percentage" data-bind="value:percent, applyKendo:{}" />
</div>    
<button data-bind="click:addRow">add row</button>
```

js:

```
function newVM(){
    self=this;
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([
        { percent: 0 },
        { percent: 0.25 },
        { percent: 0.50 }    ]);

    self.addRow = function(){ 
        this.rows.push({percent:0});
    };
    return self;
}

ko.bindingHandlers.applyKendo = {
    init:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "p0",
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            step: 0.25
        }).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new newVM());
```